# Preserving a whatsapp account from an inactive/foriegn SIM on a new device

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

My dilemma is as follows:

- I signed up for WhatsApp in a foreign country on my Tecno R7 and used it happily even after returning back to my home country.
- When i returned, I of course restored my home country SIM cards, but WhatsApp was unaffected and ran normally.
- However, my Tecno R7 malfunctioned and I had to change to a Samsung Grand Prime. So, when I tried to move my whats-app account to my new device, it initiates a new registration.
- I do not wish to open a new account and lose my old history, all my contacts were also already hooked on my old account.

Is there a way to transfer my old WhatsApp account from Tecno R7 to Samsung Grand Prime, without effecting a new registration (changing numbers)?

Answer (score 3):

Just take a backup of the WhatsApp conversations in old phone and copy the entire folder `/sdcard/WhatsApp/` and send (copy) it exactly to the same location in your new phone..

Now open WhatsApp from new phone and Enter the desired number (It may or may not require verification)
After verification is over, it'll prompt you asking for restoring chat backups..
Just restore them.

The latest version of WhatsApp supports backing up of data to Google Drive.
So, if you can update to a latest version, better sync it and try the same.